# Class name is marked as 'not covered' while running code coverage in Android Studio

Tags: android, code-coverage

I have tried AndroidStudio's code coverage feature and I have met a strange issue:

It is marks the tested class's name as 'not covered' code.
How is that possible? Is that a bug?

Picture here:

[image]

As you can see it has one method with 4 lines and each one of them is covered. So why is the red line at the class's name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using a `static` method, so the `class` itself is never created as an `object`, therefore never testing that ability.

Comment: Well okay, and how does one tests a static method with coverage?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700179/junit-testing-helper-class-with-only-static-methods like this

Answer (score 3):

I tried the lombok [@UtilityClass](https://projectlombok.org/features/experimental/UtilityClass), it helped to ignore the class name and code coverage was improved to be 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Since also a class with a static function has a default no-argument constructor, your code coverage tool will complain. A good way to solve this, is by adding a private constructor.

```
private EmailValidator() {
}
```