# initializationError when running Junit test in static

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, junit, junit4

I have been on a search recently for an answer to my question and I cannot seem to find it. I am trying to execute a simple test to run a JUnit test in static. When I try to execute the test I receive the following Failure.

java.lang.Exception: Method SimpleINt()should not be static.

I have JUnit 4 and hamcrest installed and pathsbuilt. 
(I am still new to Selenium/Java so I am sure there is an easy explanation for this.)

```
package iMAP;

import org.junit.Test;


public class Test1 {



@Test
public static  void SimpleINt ()
{
    int i = 34;
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700179/junit-testing-helper-class-with-only-static-methods

Comment: Remove the `static` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

The JUnit [documentation](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/Test.html) for @Test states:

> The Test annotation tells JUnit that the public void method to which it is attached can be run as a test case. To run the method, JUnit first constructs a fresh **instance** of the class then invokes the annotated method. Any exceptions thrown by the test will be reported by JUnit as a failure.

So, what is implicitly said here: the expectation is that @Test is **only** used for **non static** methods.

Beyond that: don't use keywords because you *can*. Learn what they mean. And **static** is something that you rather avoid (instead of using it all over the place).

Answer (score 0):

Junit Methods should not be `static` as much I read and study. Just delete `Static` and try this:

```
package iMAP;

import org.junit.Test;

public class Test1 {

@Test
public void SimpleINt ()
{
    int i = 34;
    System.out.println(i);
}
}
```